# "replay" old commits over new ones

Tags: git

We have a website whose codebase we develop using git. When branches are merged into `master`, that goes to production.

We had a situation where we developed `featureA` and deployed it. Unfortunately, there were some problems in the deployment, and we had to roll the website back using the web-hosts on-board restore system.

This site is a Drupal website, and there are certain files that act as "config in code". Because of this, we export production's config files into a separate branch called `prod-config`.

So, after the restore, since production has changes in its configuration -- which is actually the pre-deploy settings, those changes show up as new commits in the `prod-config` branch.

This effectively undoes commits in the `featureA` branch that included updates to the config files. So now, the branch `featureA` is fully merged into `master`, but the changes to config files that I want to re-deploy are overwritten in new commits.

What is the "proper" way to re-play or re-do old commits that are effectively undone in newer commits?

Of course, I can just checkout the commit in the state that I want, copy the config files over, and commit those changes. But I wonder if there is a way using git commands to do what I need to do now.

Comment: Just go to particular commit.

Comment: @Antoniossss the question is, how does that get committed at head?

Comment: *how does that get committed at head* - can you explain? I have no clue what that mean

Comment: @Antoniossss http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/git/what-is-HEAD-in-git.html

Comment: I know what HEAD is, I just don't understand your question.

Comment: do a HARD RESET. I wrote I don't understand what you want because *how does that get committed at head?* does not mean *how to make pariticular commit the new HEAD*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the "proper" way to re-play or re-do old commits that are effectively undone in newer commits?

One can use `git checkout <commit> <filename>`, to revert specific files from the previous commit, and then add the reverted configuration file in a new commit.

Answer (score 0):

In comment you explained that you want *make any particular commit HEAD?*

To do this, you just have to RESET branch of your choice to that commit. This way, selected commit will become current branche's head.

```
git reset [--soft | --mixed [-N] | --hard | --merge | --keep] [-q] [<commit>]
```

After that you can `push --force-with-lease` to update remote branch.

More details here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset